# iOS keychain randomly returning -25300 error (aka errSecItemNotFound)

Tags: ios, keychain

My app is facing a strange keychain behaviour: sometimes it returns `-25300` status instead of credentials that definitely exist. The consequence: logged in users randomly become "logged out".

App restart doesn't help, only new user authorization.

Somehow it seems like items just disappear from the keychain.

After looking closer at code that saves and reads data from keychain and comparing it with Apple's samples, I noticed that we don't use `kSecAttrService` attribute when saving items of `kSecClassGenericPassword`.

Here some code snippets:

```
func saveData(_ data: Data, for key: String) -> OSStatus {
        let query: [CFString : Any] = [
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrAccount: key,
            kSecValueData: data,
            kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly
        ]
        return SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
    }
```

```
func readData(for key: String) -> String? {
        let query: [CFString: Any] = [
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrAccount: key,
            kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue as Any,
            kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitOne
        ]
        var result: AnyObject?
        _ = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
            SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
        }
        return (result as? Data).flatMap {
            String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8)
        }
    }
```

So, may the absence of `kSecAttrService` when saving `kSecClassGenericPassword` items be the reason why keychain items become unreachable for some reason, or is there any other reason?

Thanks

Comment: hey have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly` flag, you have to ensure the protected data is available. There is a method for that in the `AppDelegate` that notifies you when this event occurs or you could add an observer and listen for the event `protectedDataDidBecomeAvailableNotification`. Documentation of the delegate method can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623044-applicationprotecteddatadidbecom) and documentation of the notification can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623039-protecteddatadidbecomeavailablen).

Comment: Thank you for your response, i’ll check this method out